# How to put Christmas light net on top of very tall tree

Tags: lighting

I have a 9 meters tall tree, and 5 christmas lights nets. I have a 5 meter ladder, some ropes, some 3 meter long sticks, and some other tools.

I want to cover the tree with the christmas lights from the very top, but is a pain and we cannot reach the top.

We're 3 people trying to do so. The net is a little problematic because sometimes it get stuck in the branches.

Anybody has a good idea of how can we achieve it? We've been trying 3 days in a row and still no success!

Comment: Two options.  Rent a man lift. Hire some fairies.

Comment: climb up the tree and schlep them over the top.

Comment: Is it a live tree or a cut tree?

Comment: reaching the topnof a tree is not in the realm of home improvement ... perhaps yoh may get some ideas at https://gardening.stackexchange.com/

Comment: hire someone that has a drone powerful enough to fly the light string over the tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

9m isn't tremendously tall as trees go. I've worked (a little) with a paint roller extension pole that was about 4.5m long at full extension. If you can rent or buy one or more of these and stand with it on the ladder that'll get you near the top of the tree.

A safer alternative could be scaffolding (rent or buy). Here in the US it is commonly available in units with height about 2m. Two of those would have you standing about 4m above ground; three could have you standing at the same height with safety rails surrounding you to protect against falling. This plus the long paint roller pole could put the top of the tree within your reach -- so long as the tree is relatively columnar in its growth habit and the light netting isn't too heavy to manage on the end of such a long pole/lever.